# Facebook Graph API started to returning empty array for comments & likes

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This question marked as already answered. **It is a mistake!** Clearly, it's not the same question.

There is nothing about /{object-id}/comments or /{object-id}/likes on changelog. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.12)

These methods still have document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/comments

I have a Graph API script running for years. It's basically fetching all comments and likes with proxy user ids. 10 days ago its stopped. I tried with Graph API Explorer and different applications/users tokens but still not working. Object 1647859165304575 is a public post.

```
curl -i -X GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/1647859165304575/likes?access_token=<access token sanitized>"

{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTYxMTEzNDY5MjI2NzgzMQZDZD",
      "after": "MTAyMTE1NDMxODI5MTE0MDgZD"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/1647859165304575/likes?access_token=<access token sanitized>&pretty=0&limit=25&after=MTAyMTE1NDMxODI5MTE0MDgZD"
  }
}
```

It has paging information but data array always empty. Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: What happened when it stopped? Did you get a stack-trace error?

Comment: It just started to return empty array: "data": [ ]

Comment: It is working fine with page access token. Facebook doesn't allow to get data from any page anymore. You should page admin. But I couldn't find this information in change logs.

Comment: the duplicate is correct, you just can´t get the user info from ANY page anymore. the accepted answer tells you where to find the info in the changelog.